# How query all folders of a volume?

Tags: query, files, subfolder, volumes

I want to query a list of all folders in a specific volume in my front-end template (loggedin users only). I'll need the folderId to display all files of the selected folder.

The idea is to show a list of folders on the left side, right displays a list of files in the selected folder on the left side. The folders need to be the same as in the backend.

```
{% set assets = craft.assets().volume('handle').folderId(folderId) %}
<ul class="files_folders">
    {% for folder in folders %}
        <li><a href="{{ url('folderId=' ~ folder.id) }}">{{ folder.title }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
<ul class="files__list">
    {% for asset in assets %}
        <li><a href="{{ craft.digitalDownload.url(asset, options) }}">{{ asset.title }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`craft\services\Assets::getAllDescendantFolders`](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v4/craft-services-assets.html#method-getalldescendantfolders) to get a list of folders in a given folder. To list all folders in the root folder of the volume, you first need to find the root folder using [`craft\services\Assets::getRootFolderByVolumeId`](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v4/craft-services-assets.html#method-getrootfolderbyvolumeid).

```
{% set myVolume = craft.app.volumes.getVolumeByHandle('handle') %}
{% set rootFolder = craft.app.assets.getRootFolderByVolumeId(myVolume.id) %}
{% set foldersInRootFolder = craft.app.assets.getAllDescendantFolders(rootFolder) %}
```

This will return an array of [`VolumeFolder`](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v4/craft-models-volumefolder.html) models that you can iterate through. If you need a hierarchical list, you can access the children with the [`VolumeFolder::children` property](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v4/craft-models-volumefolder.html#children), or use [`craft\services\Assets::getFolderTreeByFolderId`](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v4/craft-services-assets.html#method-getfoldertreebyfolderid) to get a hierarchical list. To find all assets in a given folder, use an asset query with the `folderId` parameter.